# What is the difference between class.super.method and class.method?

Tags: java, class, super

Even though both versions of the code below works, I'm wondering which one is the "more correct"/"standard" approach and why. Thanks.

Version 1:

```
public class SomeClass extends OtherClass{

    public boolean someMethod() {
        ActionListener s = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                SomeClass.super.method();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
public class SomeClass extends OtherClass{

    public boolean someMethod() {
        ActionListener s = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                SomeClass.method();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In other words...

`SomeClass.method();` or `SomeClass.super.method();`

Similarly, when should I use `method()` and when should I use `super.method()`?

Many thanks.

Comment: They will only call the same method if your class doesn't override its super class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They **are not** "more correct"/"standard", both methods calls have completely different meaning as they call different methods:

`SomeClass.method()`; calls method `method()` of the `SomeClass`
(and the method() must be declared static for it to work)

`SomeClass.super.method();` calls method `method()` of the `OtherClass`.

Similarly, use `method()` to call the `method()` defined in the given scope, `super.method()` if you want to call parent's class implementation (even if the `method()` is override in the subclass).

Comment: I know this is a pretty amateur question, but when would I use the `method()` of the `SomeClass` and when would I use the `method()` of the `OtherClass`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you would like to use the OtherClass version not the SomeClass version. I dont know what you don't understand. OtherClass method() can return A, SomceClass method returns B, if inside SomeClass you need A for some reason, the only way of getting is by explicit calling OtherClass.method()

Comment: Thank you. To confirm, as I understand it, as @Bruno Toffolo mentioned: If I do not override `method()` in `SomeClass`, then both calls are identical. Is that correct? Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `method()` in your code seems to be a static method on your `OtherClass`.

In general, to make it explicitly clear for anyone reading your code that you are invoking a static method on a class within your object's hierarchy, you can prefix the call with the class' name: `OtherClass.method()` (as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349442/calling-method-versus-class-method))

If you're **not overriding** the static `method()` in your subclass, it is common to invoke the parent class' method simply with `method()`, or explicitly with `OtherClass.method()`, as mentioned above. You don't need to prefix the call with `super.`.

If you **are overriding** the static `method()` in your subclass, then calling `method()` or `SomeClass.method()` from within your `SomeClass` will have the same effect of invoking the static method defined in `SomeClass`.
If you *do* want to invoke a parent class' static method that is hidden because your subclass is overriding it, you could either call `super.method()` (if you're in the direct subclass that is overriding it), or again be explicit about it and use `OtherClass.method()`.